# Does docker container app go to sleep when hosted on Azure Web App Free Tier?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I know when deploying a regular app to an App Service it will go to sleep when idle and there is an option for Basic+ tiers to keep the app on.

I couldn't find this option for a containerised app service on free tier and my app doesn't seem to go to sleep.

Wanted to find out if anyone knows if the docker container goes to sleep when hosted on the Azure Web App service free tier?

29/10/2019

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A docker container will cease to run after a period of 20 minutes of inactivity.

You need to use a standard or higher tier to access the Always On setting.

You could keep your container up by making a request to it before the timeout elapses using an Azure Automation account.  However, this will increase the cost when using an App Service Plan on the Basic Tier.